# Joomla: Allowing a user to upload an image

Tags: file-upload, joomla2.5

Alright so I learned that to have an upload button on a page, what you do is basically call a php file (call is upload.php) that would upload a file to the server. I have no idea where I am supposed to put the php file inside the server so I can call it.

I feel stupid because I can't find any answers online. I am getting very frustrated and confused because I am told I need to create a database but I have no idea how to edit a database in Joomla. I took a class in SQL so I don't have to learn about that. I just don't know where it is. I was also told I need to make a component. But this is confusing because all I want to do is have an upload button that will upload an image to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration. I've got the basic idea on what you are trying to do. Here are a couple of options:

1. You might wanna take a look at [Joomla! Extensions Directory ™](http://extensions.joomla.org/). You might just find there a component or a module that already does this for you.
2. If you want to do it on your own, than you need to create a small module or a component inside Joomla! Please refer to the [Joomla! Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org) or tutorials on this topic. Please note that you won't get this working instantly, because you first need to understand how Joomla! works. So your upload.php file will go in your module / component files. I don't think you need to do any SQL.
3. Now the part with "allowing a user" is a bit confusing... you want to "allow" any user to upload things to your server or just let's say, registered users? Generally uploading scripts need to be very strong from the security point of view. If this is the case, that you need to do a search for [Joomla! ACL](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2012/item/639-Joomla-ACL-Access-Levels)

Comment: I have tried using the upload.php file in the components folder com_upload. When I push the upload button it gives me error 404. I read about components and found you call it with index.php?option=com_upload. I get another error though:

Error loading component: com_upload, 1
Error loading component: com_upload, 1
Error loading component: com_upload, 1

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\components\com_upload\Upload.php on line 13

Right now I am doing it with XAMPP so it is localhost that is why I have that index set as the upload directory. 

Thanks for your help

Comment: Components also need a manifest file to be installed. If you can share some code on github or something maybe we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a form and add the "media" field type.

http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

You can also opt for the "file" field types to allow different types of fields.

Both fields can be added using the Joomla Component Creator: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

And you might also want to take a look at [K2](http://getk2.org/) which has an excellent image upload functionality that allows scaling of images into three different sizes.